# How do I uninstall dwagent from a linux machine?

Tags: linux, vnc, uninstall

I followed the instructions [here](https://hellocomtec.com/collab/knowledge-base/article/install-dwservice-on-linux) to install dwagent on some linux server.

I can connect to the server fine, but the screen share/capture isn't working for whatever reason, so I want to uninstall dwagent.

Unfortunately, there's no instructions on the site I used to install dwagent that states how to uninstall dwagent.

The installer itself only has options to install or run dwagent.

My internet searches only yielded windows 10 uninstallation instructions or usage of some command "dwaguninstall", which doesn't appear in /usr/share or any of the normal path locations.

I have the dwagent service stopped and disabled, but how do I get the files off of my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo bash /usr/share/dwagent/native/uninstall
```

This is also mentioned by Marco Giannini blog (in Italian) at https://www.marcosbox.org/2020/03/dwservice-accesso-remoto-pc.html